# Как организовать DAO?

Tags: java-ee, java

Пишу веб-приложение на java ee. Организовал `connection pool` для соединения с `db mysql`, создал классы сущностей. Теперь необходимо реализовать прослойку между db и приложением. Знаю, что для этого используется шаблон DAO. Можете рассказать для чайника как его организовать, что лучше почитать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Наверно я бы делал

1. интерфейс с методами работы с бд, стандартный CRUD
2. абстрактный класс (AbstractBaseDao)в котором "прятал" коннекты к бд, методы - open(), close();
3. создавал класс реализации всего этого, наследовался от абстрактного класса, что позволило бы уже иметь готовые методы для подключения к бд и ссылку на нее и реализовывал интерфейс с методами.

Так же хороший вариант - методы интерфейса не выносить, а оставить их в абстрактом классе.

Иногда это все может быть избыточной архитектурой, потому можно все уместить в один класс.

Преимущества ДАО интейфейса - позволит сменить БД не затрагивая логику программы.

Comment: где-то видел интерфейс-дженерик, также были варианты с абстрактным классом. А нет какой-нибудь стандартной реализации?

Comment: необходимо ли использование factory при реализации dao?

Comment: интерфейс-дженерик - наверно это больше работает как шаблон, т.е. у тебя есть группа разных объектов, но у них одинаковые операции с бд, например есть груши, яблоки и телевизоры и их надо всех хранить в бд, тогда ты просто создаешь шаблон-интерфейс, а при его реализации в дженерики указываешь объект, обычно IDE дополнит реализацию методами нужного типа, а в каждой реализации интерфейса ты уже правильно организуешь хранении объекта. Стандартные - это примеры в интернете, а для своего небольшого проекта можно с этим и не заморачиватся =)

Comment: > необходимо ли использование factory при реализации dao? 

Если вы имеете в виду DAO как о обьект, то нет. Если же шаблон DAO, - то да. Этот шаблон подразумевает наличие factory обьекта который будет предоставлять доступ к всем ДАО обьектам

Comment: я имел в виду шаблон dao. может, скинете ссылку на пример использования?

Comment: ссылка на [java.sun.com][1] 


  [1]: http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DataAccessObject.html

Comment: Если Вы используете JavaEE, то Вам доступен сервис CDI (Context and Dependency Injection). Правда, нужно смотреть, какие именно компоненты JavaEE предоставляет Ваш сервер приложений. В этом случае Factory используется практически сама собой: класс, использующий DAO, делает @Inject интерфейса DAO, а другой класс, отвечающий за общение с MySQL, его реализует.